# Django email host

Tags: django, email, dreamhost

The issue is that I cannot send email from another email unless the email has to same domain name as the email from the host. I can only write mail from emails like `test@stackzzz.com` but can't do `zzzz@gmail.com`
My mail server is on Dreamhost if that helps

Here are the settings

```
# django.contrib.auth.LOGIN_URL = '/'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.stackzzz.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'contact@stackzzz.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '123'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: yes, that's how email works...

Comment: You want to be able to send email from multiple domains? why? If you're running a site from stackzzz.com why would you send an email from gmail?

Comment: It's a contact form. So they can send a mail to contact@stackzzz.com

Comment: It seems like it's dreamhost's policy.
- You must use a FROM address that’s on the same website you’re sending email from